# ASP.NET Core 5 WebAPI - Azure AD - Call Graph API Using Azure Ad Access Token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a WebAPI using .NET 5 using Azure AD for authentication of the user. I am using Postman to generate the Access Token and the WebAPI Works when passing Access Token as Bearer.

I want to call Graph API to get the user Calendar & Profile using the Access Token but unable to do so. I have followed few articles mentioned below with no luck.

Invalid Authentication Token error when using the Access Token to call /me Graph API
[image]

App registration to use My Org Only. I have added Delegated permissions to Graph API.

[image]

Created A custom scope using Expose An API as the WebAPI Was throwing Signature Invalid Error.

My WebAPI Configure Services in StartUp.cs Code:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
```

My AppSettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<Domain",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "TenantId": "<TenantId>"
  },
```

I have tried to follow couple of articles which suggest On Behalf Of Flow

https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core

[Struggle with MS Graph and asp.net Core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119805/struggle-with-ms-graph-and-asp-net-core-api)

I am lost any help is much appreciated.

EDIT1:

I tried Implementing the solution suggested by Farid.
The postman output was returning HTML Response to Sign In. It is a ASP.NET Core 5 WebAPI so I changed the ConfigureServices code to below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)              
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
         .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
         .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I receive the following Error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**Update:**

I was able to resolve the error by using below code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()                    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I am able to read my profile but not able to obtain Calendar Items. It could be due to Admin Consent Requirement.

Comment: Would you kindly have a try the solution and let me know if that works exactly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron: Thanks a lot for helping out and providing the solution. I am trying it and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: My pleasure, keep me updated, even you requires further assistance on this.

Comment: Hello, is there anything else that I can assist on this?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It's a .NET 5 WebAPI I am building and .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp doesn't seem to be available. Any particular package needs to be installed?

Comment: Yes, you should add `microsoft.identity.web`  version I am using is `1.4.0` on reference. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron. I have updated the question with error I am receiving.

Comment: Please have a look on the updated answer on `Note` section or visit [github link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Startup.cs) you will get complete example just modify with my solution.

Comment: Hello did you able to run the github project? Was the problem resolved? Feel free to share if any further assistance required on this.

Comment: Glad to help you, regarding your `calendar` issue you must have `Admin Consent`, if you can post another question it I can assist there to maintain question as unique problem with access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your given information it seems your token has expired, so firstly try to regenerate that, additionally, you have added `Delegated permissions` that's fine but I doubt you haven added the grant admin consent after adding Graph API permission. So its mandatory and please double check that. See the below screen capture. Please follow the below steps to get token and user info using `Microsoft Graph API`

***Grant Admin Consent:***

[image]

***Token Aquisition Example:***

Check the `appsettings.json` it should be like below:

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "yourdemain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {

    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***Startup.cs***

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }
```

> ***Note:*** You can ignore below two service from the `ConfigureServices` under `startup.cs`    `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes) .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))`
> because I am using `Graph API SDK` and reading scope from
> `appsettings.json` so in the sample I am using local scope for your
> test case. So its not required or upto you.

***Controller Action:***

```
public async Task<object> GetUserInfoFromGraphAPI()
        {

            try
            {

                //Initialize on behalf of user token aquisition service

                var _tokenAcquisition = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;

                //define the scope
                string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

                //Getting token from Azure Active Directory
                string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

                //Request Grap API end point
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"));

                //Passing Token For this Request
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

                //Get User into from grpah API
                dynamic userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());


                return userInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

***Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** For complete solution please visit the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Startup.cs)

Hope it will help you to achive your goal.