# Configuring Graph API through Azure Portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to get Graph API to work using only the Azure Portal. For example, I can configure Azure AD authentication in my code ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core)) or I can configure it through the Azure Portal ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#:%7E:text=Sign%20in%20to%20the%20Azure,in%20the%20identity%20provider%20dropdown.)).

Is there some way to configure Microsoft Graph through the Azure Portal like in my second example? So effectively, I would not need to write any configuration in my startup class and let the app service itself configure and inject the `ITokenAcquisition` or, even better, the `GraphServiceClient`?

The reason I am trying to do this is that I don't really want to deal with handling token caching myself and was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: You could call inject that this way,    `var _tokenAcquisition =this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;` then pass your `scope` once you do that then aquire the token like this: ` string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);`. Therefoire, I would say, definately using `GraphServiceClient` you would be able to redeem additional hassle.

Comment: You could [`check here for details implementation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001458/asp-net-core-5-webapi-azure-ad-call-graph-api-using-azure-ad-access-token/69007174#69007174). Feel free to share if you have any further concern on this.

Comment: I am not quite sure how your solution is any different from the first  example I posted. I still would have to configure a distributed cache with the example you provided. I am looking for a way to skip this step and just let Azure handle the configuration and hosting of the distributed cache. So I can just set up the app registration, the API permissions and then add the authentication provider through the Azure portal and everything else will "magically work".

Comment: Use `GraphServiceClient` then that might work for you.